# Cartopy behavior when plotting projected data

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am using cartopy to draw my maps. Its a great tool!
For some of my data I have the problem that the data is not properly mapped around 0deg or the dateline. See the example below.

I know the same feature from matplotlib.basemap, where it can be solved by using the add_cyclic routine. I wondered if somebody can recommend how to best fix this problem in cartopy.

Thanks!

Alex

[image: Cartopy problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cartopy development team has included the required feature in the developoment branch. For details see [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/393#issuecomment-36603533)

Answer (score 8):

When plotting global data like this you will always need to add a cyclic point to your input data and coordinate. I don't believe Cartopy currently includes a function to do this for you, but you can do it yourself quite simply for the time being. Assuming you have a 1d array of longitudes and a 2d array of data where the first dimension is latitude and the second is longitude:

```py
import numpy as np

dlon = lons[1] - lons[0]
new_lons = np.concatenate((lons, lons[-1:] + dlon))
new_data = np.concatenate((data, data[:, 0:1]), axis=1)
```

If you have different shaped data or coordinates then you will need to adjust this to your needs.

Comment: The cartopy master branch on Github now contains a function to do this: cartopy.util.add_cyclic_point. This should make it into the next release v0.11.0.