# Matplotlib polar contourf plot: continuous across theta origin

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates, contourf

I have data in format `E`(`freq`, `theta`), where `E` is a 2D array and `freq` and `theta` are 1D arrays.

The following portion of code produces the attached figure. However, I would like to make the contourf plot continuous across the 0-degree origin (i.e. no wedge of white space along the 0 azimuth).

I've explored the matplotlib documentation, and posted questions very extensively and can't seem to find a solution for this issue. Any ideas?

Code:

```
[r, th] = np.meshgrid(freq,theta)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

cntf = ax.contourf(th,r,np.log10(E),cmap='jet',extend='both',
    levels=np.linspace(np.mean(np.log10(E)), np.amax(np.log10(E)), 15))

ax.set_rlim(0, .3)
label_position=ax.get_rlabel_position()
ax.text(np.radians(label_position+25),ax.get_rmax()/1.5,'f (Hz)',
        rotation=label_position,ha='center',va='center')
```

Produced plot:
[image: Directional wave spectrum]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129714/9324652

[image]

```
dtheta = np.diff(theta).mean()
wrp_theta = np.concatenate((theta, theta[-1:] + dtheta))
wrp_E = np.concatenate((E, E[0:1, :]), axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew!

Issue was that the numpy array needs a cyclical point in order for the plot to be continuous. Worked perfect!

Comment: I think it should be `wrp_E = np.concatenate((E, E[0:1, :]), axis=1)`.